# How to query multiple entries at once

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, reactive, sql++

I am using spring boot reactive and Couchbase

```
Flux<Item> findByLocation_LocationIdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(String locationId);
```

Just to point here I am accessing Location.locationId. Location object has locationId field in main document

Also below properties is not printing the generated Couchbase query, if anyone can help with that too,

logging:
level:
org.springframework.data: DEBUG

The response is fine when database has only one entry, but when the db has more than one entry matching criteria it throws "Source emitted more than one item" .

My controller is returning

```
Flux<Item>
```

Comment: Which are you using, CouchDB or Couchbase? You have both tagged, but you mention CouchDB in the question.

Comment: Removed tag couchDB, spring almost has similar querystructure that was reason added that tag

Answer (score 1):

Following two annotations are mandatory or it keep returning the exception

@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed

@Ghrissology I already had ReactiveCouchbaseRepository

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the spring Data change the query based on the return type.
if you want one result it use getSingleResult() automatically :

```
Item findByLocation_LocationIdOrderByCreatedAtDesc(String locationId);
```

in you case, i think he didn't understand the return type because you didn't implement a ReactiveCrudRepository:

```
public interface ReactiveItemRepository
  extends ReactiveCrudRepository<item, String> {}
```

Comment: ReactiveCrudRepository is not applicable in my case because I am using reactive

I am already extended ReactiveCouchbaseRepository